# ionic 4 angular when try to run the code i get not found error

Tags: ionic4

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept', '*/*');
headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-WWW-form- 
urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' );

const options = new RequestOptions({ headers });
const object = {} as any;

object.CityName =   '';
const postParams = {
  objectData  :   object
} as any;

postParams.dtsessionid = 'DB9C56E7E4BD40EDA2069DF38A8C2036';
postParams.objectData = JSON.stringify(object).replace(/"/g, 
'\'').replace(/&/g, 'and');

this.http.post('https://askfleet.buzzfleet.net:3920/city/getList', 
postParams, options)
  .subscribe(data => {
   }, error => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  });
```

Comment: Please Add more details. also share what error are you getting

Comment: it gives session id not found 

i want to post form data in this format

objectData: {'CityName':''}
dtsessionid: 7D0EC0BECD92498BB3C38E2CB0C24578

but it going as

{
  "objectData": "{'CityName':''}",
  "dtsessionid": "DB9C56E7E4BD40EDA2069DF38A8C2036"
}: